# VBA - Creating a chart where each series represents a data point

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a bit of VBA that will automatically populate a scatter chart such that each row (x,y) in a table represents a series i.e. one point per series. I attach below my code so far. But when I come to run it it fails with the following run time error

"Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim NPOINTS As Integer
Dim NVAL(1000) As Range, XVAL(1000) As Range, YVAL(1000) As Range

Sheets("Scenario").Select
Range("B4").Select
NPOINTS = Worksheets("Scenario").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Set Scenario = Worksheets("Scenario")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select

 NVAL0 = "B3"
 XVAL0 = "C3"
 YVAL0 = "D3"

 For i = 1 To NPOINTS

       Set NVAL(i) = Cells(Range(NVAL0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(NVAL0).Column)
       Set XVAL(i) = Cells(Range(XVAL0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(XVAL0).Column)
       Set YVAL(i) = Cells(Range(YVAL0).Offset(i, 0).Row, Range(YVAL0).Column)

       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = NVAL(i)
       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = XVAL(i)
       ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).YValues = YVAL(i)

 Next
```

End Sub

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y-values in a scatter plot are stored in `Values`, not `YValues`, so you need to change the last line accordingly.

Comment: D'oh I knew it would be something simple. Thank you!